# Routing/NAT with 2 VLAN on SG500X

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I will simplify to the maximum :

I have a router Cisco SG500X.
We have 2 VLAN (VLAN 10 IP:192.168.1.1, VLAN 20 IP:172.16.254.254) with intervlan routing. It's works.

Cisco default gateway is 192.168.1.254 (IP of the internet modem).

- A computer in VLAN 10 can contact a computer in VLAN 20 and can go on the internet.
- A computer in VLAN 20 can contact a computer in VLAN 10 but cannot go on the internet.

I don't find which route/parameters i have to add. SG500X seems don't NAT ?

Thank you for your help.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

1. if it has an IP (192.168.1.254) your "Internet modem" is a Router
2. it knows what to do with traffic going back to 192.168.1.x because it has a direct connection to that network
3. it probably has no clue on how to reach network 172.16.x.y

So:

Add a static route on your internet router (192.168.1.254) telling that it can reach network 172.16.x.y/Z using 192.168.1.1 ad gateway